# jQueryUI Autocomplete Web Forms User Control - Multiple Intances

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui, webforms, user-controls

Morning folks.

My Ajax Script Manager is registering my script and adding my function to end request. This is keeping the script persistent across partial updates.

I am pushing DataTable values as items to a javascript array in the codebehind.

I am seeing recommendations to use an httphandler.ashx instead and use it to return data as JSON, but I am not sure it will meet my goal of multiple instances, I'd like to be able to pass it parameters to pull different data not static.

My goal is to create an asp web form user control textbox with jquery ui autocomplete that developers can plug into with just a datatable and column names in mind.

At this point in time, I can pass it a datatable and a string for the column name for the text and value.

The problem is that if there are multiple instances of this user control on one page, the source for the controls are interfering with one another.

I know the source array is already declared as I'm instantiating new controls and that is part of the problem, I need to be able to handle the source in a $(this) fashion, unique to each of the .autocomplete elements, but I'm having trouble getting it.

Thanks in advance.

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        EndRequest();
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    });
    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) { }
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        var data = new Array;
        function pushData(dataTextField, dataValueField) {
            data.push({
                label: dataTextField,
                value: dataValueField
            });
        }
        $('.txtData').autocomplete({
            maxResults: 20,
            source: function (request, response) {
                var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term);
                response(results.slice(0, this.options.maxResults));
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                $(this).closest('.divMain').find('[id$="hidData"]').val(ui.item.value);
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            }
        }); pushData('Field1', 'Field2');//n times
    }
</script>
```

User Control Markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>        
    <style>
        .ui-autocomplete {
            max-height: 100px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        * html .ui-autocomplete {
            height: 100px;
        }
        .divWrapper {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .divMain {
            display: flex;
        }            
    </style>                
    <div class="divWrapper">
        <div class="divMain">
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidData" />                
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtData" CssClass="txtData" />
        </div>
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

User Control Code Behind:

```
public void DataBind(DataTable dt, string DataTextField, string DataValueField)
{                                
    string[][] arrObject = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new string[] { r[DataTextField].ToString(), r[DataValueField].ToString() }).ToArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script>");        
    sb.Append("$(document).ready(function(){");//ready
    sb.Append("EndRequest();");
    sb.Append("var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();");
    sb.Append("prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);");
    sb.Append("prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);");
    sb.Append("});");                
    sb.Append("function InitializeRequest(sender, args){");//init        
    sb.Append("}");                
    sb.Append("function EndRequest(sender, args){");//end        
    sb.Append("var data = new Array;");
    sb.Append("function pushData(dataTextField, dataValueField) {");
    sb.Append("data.push({");
    sb.Append("label: dataTextField,");
    sb.Append("value: dataValueField");
    sb.Append("});");
    sb.Append("}");
    sb.Append("$('.txtData').autocomplete({");
    sb.Append("maxResults: " + maxResults + ",");
    sb.Append("source: function(request, response) {");
    sb.Append("var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term);");
    sb.Append("response(results.slice(0, this.options.maxResults));");
    sb.Append("},");        
    sb.Append("select: function(event, ui) {");
    sb.Append("event.preventDefault();");
    sb.Append("$(this).val(ui.item.label);");
    sb.Append("$(this).closest('.divMain').find('[id$=\"hidData\"]').val(ui.item.value);");                
    sb.Append("},");
    sb.Append("focus: function(event, ui){");
    sb.Append("event.preventDefault();");
    sb.Append("$(this).val(ui.item.label);");
    sb.Append("}");
    sb.Append("});");
    foreach (string[] arrFields in arrObject)
    {
        sb.Append("pushData('" + arrFields[0] + "', '" + arrFields[1] + "');");
    }
    sb.Append("}");        
    sb.Append("</script>");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "AutoCompleteData", sb.ToString(), false);
}
```

Content Page Markup:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>                       
        <asp:TabContainer runat="server" ID="tcMain" Width="100%">
            <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Test">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <uc:AutoCompleteDropDown runat="server" ID="ucDDL1" />
                    <uc:AutoCompleteDropDown runat="server" ID="ucDDL2" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>
        </asp:TabContainer>            
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Content Page Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Connection connection = MyConnections.GetConnection();
        List<SqlParameter> sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>() { new SqlParameter("@QueryID", "GetStuff") };
        DataSet ds1 = connection.ExecuteSP("spSomeStoredProc1", sqlParams.ToArray());
        ucDDL1.DataBind(ds1.Tables[0], "Field1", "Field2");
        DataSet ds2 = connection.ExecuteSP("spSomeStoredProc2", sqlParams.ToArray());
        ucDDL2.DataBind(ds2.Tables[0], "Field1", "Field2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve this example seems overly complex and may be difficult to replicate. You may get a better response if you can identify the specific issue or make a more specific example

Answer (score 0):

Here it is if anyone is interested. I had to change how I use my jquery selectors in several places. I was stepping all over my other $('.autocompletes'). I also made use of the control's client id and id

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        EndRequestucDDL1();
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequestucDDL1);
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestucDDL1);
    });
    function InitializeRequestucDDL1(sender, args) {
    }
    function EndRequestucDDL1(sender, args) {
        var data = new Array;
        function pushData(dataTextField, dataValueField) {
            data.push({
                label: dataTextField,
                value: dataValueField
            });
        }
        var uc = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_tcMain_ctl00_ucDDL1_txtData');
        $(uc).autocomplete({
            maxResults: 2,
            source: function (request, response) {
                var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term);
                response(results.slice(0, this.options.maxResults));
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                $(this).closest('.divMain').find('[id$="hidData"]').val(ui.item.value);
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            }
        });
        pushData('Field1', 'Field2');
    }
</script>
```

Code Behind:

```
public void DataBind(DataTable dt, string DataTextField, string DataValueField)
{
    var uc = this;
    string[][] arrObject = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new string[] { r[DataTextField].ToString(), r[DataValueField].ToString() }).ToArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<script>");        
    sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function(){");//ready
    sb.AppendLine("EndRequest" + this.ID + "();");
    sb.AppendLine("var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();");
    sb.AppendLine("prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest" + this.ID + ");");
    sb.AppendLine("prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest" + this.ID + ");");
    sb.AppendLine("});");                
    sb.AppendLine("function InitializeRequest" + this.ID + "(sender, args){");//init        
    sb.AppendLine("}");                
    sb.AppendLine("function EndRequest" + this.ID + "(sender, args){");//end        
    sb.AppendLine("var data = new Array;");
    sb.AppendLine("function pushData(dataTextField, dataValueField) {");
    sb.AppendLine("data.push({");
    sb.AppendLine("label: dataTextField,");
    sb.AppendLine("value: dataValueField");//ContentPlaceHolder1_tcMain_ctl00_ucDDL1_ctl00
    sb.AppendLine("});");
    sb.AppendLine("}");
    sb.AppendLine("var uc = $('#" + this.txtData.ClientID + "');");        
    sb.AppendLine("$(uc).autocomplete({");
    sb.AppendLine("maxResults: " + maxResults + ",");
    sb.AppendLine("source: function(request, response) {");
    sb.AppendLine("var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term);");
    sb.AppendLine("response(results.slice(0, this.options.maxResults));");
    sb.AppendLine("},");        
    sb.AppendLine("select: function(event, ui) {");
    sb.AppendLine("event.preventDefault();");
    sb.AppendLine("$(this).val(ui.item.label);");
    sb.AppendLine("$(this).closest('.divMain').find('[id$=\"hidData\"]').val(ui.item.value);");                
    sb.AppendLine("},");
    sb.AppendLine("focus: function(event, ui){");
    sb.AppendLine("event.preventDefault();");
    sb.AppendLine("$(this).val(ui.item.label);");
    sb.AppendLine("}");
    sb.AppendLine("});");
    foreach (string[] arrFields in arrObject)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("pushData('" + arrFields[0] + "', '" + arrFields[1] + "');");
    }
    sb.AppendLine("}");        
    sb.AppendLine("</script>");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "AutoCompleteData" + this.ID, sb.ToString(), false);
}
```